# legends are overflowing from the ggplot chart

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am using ggplot2 to chart bunch of items in one chart. Sincere there could be 1 to 60 or greater items, Iam using

```
ggplot(df, aes(Date, Value, colour=item, group=item)) + geom_point(size=0.4)    + guides(col = guide_legend(nrow = 30, byrow=TRUE))
```

to make sure I have 30 rows. If it is greater than 30 items, next legend item shows ups on the second column and so forth.

But If I have fewer items like 2 or 3, legends are overthrown from the chart window.

Is there an option to force the legend to justify vertically with ggplot?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
+ opts(legend.justification=c(0,0.8))
```

did it for me. Since version 0.9.2, `opts` has been [replaced](http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/theme.html) by `theme`:

```
+ theme(legend.justification = c(0,0.8))
```

Comment: For future reference,`opts` is depcrecated from `ggplot2` 0.9.2 forward.

Comment: @Bryan Hanson, yes, I heard about it. Have you used it? Do you know the main differences? is it better charting?

Comment: There is a transition guide which covers the change from 0.8 up to the 0.9 series, and I think it would cover most of the changes.  There is a another guide being produced that it totally up to date, expected very soon.  Join the ggplot2 Google group to be sure to get the notice.  Here is the slightly older transition guide: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/ggplot2-dev/LU0nS320318